# Why is my loop not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why is my loop not working in JavaScript?

```
for (n = 1; n<4; n++) 
{
    var my_buttons = "";
    my_buttons = my_buttons + `<div class="click" id="color${n}"></div>`;
    document.getElementById("clicky").innerHTML = my_buttons;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you receiving errors in your console window? Is it because you  are only getting your last iteration value inside of element "clicky"? I'm taking a shot in the dark...not really, that your problem is that element with id: "clicky" only has the last button inside. move your last line of your `for` loop outside and below the loop and declare `my_buttons` above the `for` loop and do a `+=` on your second line of code inside your loop.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Please include a [mcve]

Comment: I guess you need `var` : `for (var n = 1.. `

Comment: @cYrixmorten Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @cYrixmorten That would be good, but it will still work without it because the variable will just get declared as a Global.

Comment: For future questions please be more specific and post the error you get on console plus the things you have tried so far.

Comment: At the very least, your initialization (my_buttons = "") needs to go outside the loop.

Comment: @ScottMarcus right, not used to pure javascript anymore :D just answered based on lack of context and had forgotten that leaving out the declaration is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

First you were overwriting my_buttons by declaring it within the loop. Second you were adding that overwritten variable to innerHTML within the loop also, so the content never got saved together.

```
my_buttons = "";
for (let n = 1; n<4; n++) 
{
    my_buttons = my_buttons + `<div class="click" id="color${n}"></div>`;
}
document.getElementById("clicky").innerHTML = my_buttons;
```

Comment: The second problem is mainly just an inefficiency.